# How to get the validation for an array textbox with the array checkbox selected

Tags: javascript, arrays, validation

I have array of checkboxes with the specified array textbox in the corresponding rows. If the user selects the particular checkbox, for example the first three checkboxes, I want to validate for the corresponding textboxes(empty validation). How can I make this? I have tried for the entire array textboxes and it works fine. But I want validation for the checked ones only. I give the code for your reference:

```
dml=document.forms['form1'];
// get the number of elements from the document
len = dml.elements.length;
for( i=0 ; i<len ; i++)
{
    //check the textbox with the elements name
    if (dml.elements[i].id=='noofdays[]')
    {
        // if exists do the validation and set the focus to the textbox
        if (dml.elements[i].value=="")
        {
            alert("Please enter no of Days");
            dml.elements[i].focus();
            return false;     
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your quick reply. But in my process . i am getting the checkbox value as id from my database. i have give my code for your referencce.

```
<? while(($count<$rpp) && ($i<$tcount))
   {
       mysql_data_seek($res,$i);
       $_SESSION['cardid'][$i]=$row['id'];
       $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
?>

<tr>
  <td align="center" bgcolor="#e9e9e9" class="running_text"><input name="id[]" type="checkbox" id="id[]" value="<?=$row['jobid']?>" onchange="enableTextField(this)" /></td>
  <td height="28" align="center" bgcolor="#e9e9e9" class="running_text"><?=$row['jobtitle']?></td>
  <td align="center" bgcolor="#e9e9e9" class="running_text"><?=$row['jobcategoryid']?></td>
  <td align="center" bgcolor="#e9e9e9" class="running_text"><?=$row['practicename']?></td>
  <td align="center" bgcolor="#e9e9e9" class="running_text"><?=$row['subscriptiontype']?></td>
  <td width="82" align="center" bgcolor="#e9e9e9" class="running_text"><input type="text" size="1" value="0" name="noofdays[<?php echo $row['jobid']; ?>]" id="noofdays[]">
     < /td>
  <td width="28" align="center" bgcolor="#e9e9e9" class="running_text"><a href="viewjobdetails.php?jobid=<?=$row['jobid']?>&ss=<? echo $_POST['noofdays'][$jobsid];?>"><img src="images/view-detail-icon.png" width="16" height="16" title="View" /></a></td>
  <td width="31" align="center" bgcolor="#e9e9e9" class="running_text"><a onClick="return del(<?=$row['jobid']?>)" class="deleteimage"><img src="images/Delete-icon.png" width="16" height="16" title="Delete" /></a></td>
</tr>

<?     $i++; 
       $count++; 
    } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your checkbox a value that will match a class name for your text inputs. Group your
text inputs with a class name.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="lips"/> <--------Grouper

<input type="text" class='lips' />​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ <-Groupeee
<input type="text" class='lips' /> <-Groupeee
<input type="text" class='lips' />​ <-Groupee

<script type="text/javascript">
    var ckBxs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]'),
                    i = ckBxs.length;
    while (i--) {
        ckBxs[i].onchange = checkBoxCheck;
    };
    function checkBoxCheck() {
        var txBxs = document.getElementsByClassName(this.value),
                        i = cxBxs.length;
        while (i--) {

            switch (txBxs[i].class) {

                case 'lips':
                    if (txBxs[i].value != 'To what ever your checking for')
                    { alert('You\'re in focus Fool!'); };
                    break;
                    //

                case 'nextClassGroup':
                    if (txBxs[i].value != 'To what ever your checking for')
                    { alert('You\'re in focus Fool!'); };
                    break;
            };
        };
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But in my process . i am getting the checkbox value as id from my database. i have give my code for your referencce.

Comment: Friend i have modified my question slightly because i didn't gave the checkbox and inputbox in the earlier question . Please check it above

Comment: If you're pulling from the database you can still add classes just like id's. If you're going to have your database manage your html I would recommend that you have it add the classes. What you're doing is working with a 1*, "one to many", relationship anyway, because if a given checkbox manages more than one textbox, then this is the same as a one to many. You can do all that on the server.

Comment: I can't understad your reply friend. Please reply with and code example exact with my above coding